# redirect to a particular page after contact form is submitted in Magento

Tags: magento

how can i re-direct to a particular page after the user submits the contact form in Magento? form.phtml has

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

but i'm not sure where to find the php file that controls the email sending and redirects. any ideas? thanks

EDIT: found this in IndexController.php under app > code > core > Mage > Contacts > controllers

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexController.php under app > code > core > Mage > Contacts > controllers

changed

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

to

```
$this->_redirect('');
```

and it re-directs to the homepage now.

Comment: For those of you viewing this, please do not make changes to the core!  Do NOT edit this file.

Comment: Bad practice. Do not change core files.

Comment: Then what do you suggest we do? I am using Contact Us in a CMS Page as a Block.

Answer (score 14):

I know its answered, just sharing my experience. 
I had made a contact form through a CMS page. The form worked fine. But after submitting it, it would redirect to the magento contact form. To redirect it back to CMS page, i had to put

```
$this->_redirect('contactus');
```

where `contactus` is the URL identifier.

Also after redirect, the success / error message would not show up. For that i had to make changes here.

> Go to
>   /app/design/frontend/default/yourstore/template/contacts/form.phtml

```
<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
</div>
```

with:

```
<?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
```

I got the solution from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/22807/#t80385)

Comment: @noobcode Where did you put the line `$this->_redirect('contactus');` ? thanks.

Comment: @shnozolla Mage_Contacts_IndexController::postAction

Comment: if anyone is wondering, you can get the current CMS page's URL identifier with this code `$cmsPageUrlKey = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();`

Comment: This solution recommends modifying `Mage_Contacts_IndexController` in `core`. That will result in a codebase that's not safe for upgrading. Instead, create a custom module and in it, overwrite the IndexController. See Simon's answer below. In this way, you'll only be taking responsibility for `postAction` instead of the entire controller file, and at upgrade time, you'll only have to compare your `postAction` with the upgraded version, instead of the entire controller file.

Answer (score 5):

For the next person

1. go to silk software and create a new module using their module creator
   http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/
2. Enter your company name and module name
3. Then change "Need Rewrite Magento Class" to Yes
4. click "Add Class" the class name will be Mage_Contacts_IndexController
5. This will create a module with everything you need
6. Add the postAction method from the Core Controller to your newly created controller
7. Then change the redirect to redirectReferer() at the end of the postAction method

The module creator will create everything you need to overload the Contacts Controller and save you time from troubleshooting typos. Also, save yourself the trouble down the road of editing the core files directly.

DO NOT EDIT THE CORE FILES!

Answer (score 3):

Could also just create custom url redirect.

- id path - contacts/index
- request path - contacts/index
- target path - 'redirect url'

Answer (score 2):

To avoid overwriting core files and harm update compatibility, I overloaded the controller as described here: [Tutorial: Overload a controller](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller)

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <contacts>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <My_Module_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">My_Module_Contacts</My_Module_Contacts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contacts>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And rewrote `$this->_redirect('*/*/')` to `$this->_redirectReferer('contacts/index')`, so you get redirected to the previous page, and if no referer was set, to /contacts/index as a fallback.

Also I changed form.phtml from

```
<div id="messages_product_view">
  <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="messages_product_view">
  <?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
  <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

to display the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I suppose change the success message after from submitting the contacts page.

1. I used the below code in my static page

   ```
   {{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' form_action='mywebsiteurl/contacts/index/post' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
   ```
2. I override the default controller action in my custom module config.xml file.

   ```
           <routers>
               <airhotels>
                   <args>
                       <modules>
                           <apptha_airhotels before="Mage_Contacts">Apptha_Airhotels</apptha_airhotels>
                       </modules>
                   </args>
               </airhotels>
           </routers>
   ```
3. And in my custom controller(Apptha_Airhotels_ContactsController) action (postAction ) I used my custom message and redirect to custom url.

   ```
   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
   $this->_redirect($formUrl);
   ```

This form url is defined as : 
        $formUrl = basename($this->_getRefererUrl());

Answer (score 0):

A pretty dirty but easy approach is to redirect `/contact/index` to `/contact` after form submission.

Say you extend the Magento Contact in your template like here:

[image]

Add file `Magento_Contact/templates/form-submitted.phtml` with the following content:

```
<?php
header('Location: /contact');
exit;
```

Then change `Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.html` to use that template as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Contact</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form-submitted.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Everything works, including the flash message.

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

The combined solution is given in both answers from @Simon and the others

- change `$this->_redirect('*/*/')` everywhere in `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` to `$this->_redirectReferer();`
- and update the form phtml to include the error/success message by editing `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml` and adding the line `<?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>` in messages_product_view

Best to copy the files to 'local'

Comment: Copying the files to `local` is better than editing directly in `core`, but it's still not best practice, which is to rewrite the controller file in a custom module, and make your changes there. In this way, when it's time to upgrade, you'll only have to compare `postAction` to the upgraded version, instead of the entire Controller file.